# Apache ErrorDocument in an alias

Tags: apache-2.2, errordocument, mod-alias

I am trying to set a custom error document in an alias.

```
Alias /f1 "/media/data/www/f1"
<Directory "/media/data/wwww/f1">
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
        Options Includes Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        ErrorDocument 404 "Something was not found!"
</Directory>
```

This absolutely does not seem to work! The same directives in a virtual host works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

I could not find any reference that states that I cannot have custom error messages in an Alias Section.

Comment: I indeed had `wwww` instead of `www` Thanks to @Imo for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this for you and it worked fine.  It looks like you've got a typo in your directory statement. (wwww instead of www)

Comment: Thank you! As lame as it is. The typo of `wwww` was the only thing that stopped this from working :-) Phew! I wasted 2 hours trying to troubleshoot this before surrendering it to ServerFault.

Comment: It happens to us all. Often takes someone else fresh to the problem to spot it. :)